# How to know when a collection of getJSON() requests are finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to know when all of these requests are finished?

```
$.each(data.response.docs, function(i, item) {
    $.getJSON("jsp/informations.jsp?id=" + item.id, {}, function(data) {..});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could maintain a counter when each request completes, but that's a bit ugly and inelegant. Instead you could put the deferred objects returned from `$.getJSON` in to an array using `map()`. You can then apply than array to `$.when`. Something like this:

```
var requests = $.map(data.response.docs, function(i, item) {
    return $.getJSON('jsp/informations.jsp', { id: item.id }, function(data) {
        // ...
    });
}).get();

$.when.apply(requests).done(function() {
    // all requests complete...
});
```

Comment: nice! why not listen for `.always` so to also know when they fail?

Comment: `always` doesn't let you know if any of the requests failed, it just occurs after the requests complete regardless of result. If you want to know of any failures, you would use `.fail()`.

Comment: Can you provide me the ugly and inelegant version please. I have not the time to change all the code inside function(data) {}

Thanks !

Comment: @earpolicy The method above means you don't have to change the code in that function. Its the counter method which means that you would have to (hence why it's ugly)

Comment: There's no reason that wouldn't work, assuming the underlying object is valid.